# advantages of using navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have recently started working with iOS and Swift. I have noticed that a navigation bar can be implemented using UI elements, and adding buttons via Interface Builder. I have also noticed that a navigation bar can be implemented using a navigation controller, and customizing the navbar in code.

What is the advantages and circumstances of using one method over another, best practices, etc.? Is there any significant difference from a performance standpoint?

Comment: from a performance standpoint? is this a significant concern for you?

Comment: Not extremely, I just always aim for optimal performance so long as there is a significant difference. See rephrased section.

Comment: Read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) and the [UINavigationController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934) docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't really see the code of UINavigationController, so it is tough to compare the performance of a UINavigationController as opposed to a fully custom navigation controller without coding it out and performing some VERY precise tests. I would imagine that the performance difference would be minimal, if there is any detectable difference at all. If all you need is to navigate back and forth between a few specific views, a custom nav controller would work fine.

There are really a few ideas behind the delivered UINavigationController:

- Keeps your app looking how users expect an iOS app to look
- Takes care of navigation titles and links for you so you can focus on the rest of your app
- Gives users gesture controls for back, forward
- Manages the navigation stack, allowing you to easily jump between view controllers that might be further down in the stack (skip back to the homepage from a few view controllers in)
- Has a delegate property so that you can have an object that understands where the user is in the app at all times

You don't have to use the provided nav controller if you don't want to, but it offers a lot of features that might come in handy later!